# how to call ViewPager2.unregisterOnPageChangeCallback()?

Tags: android, kotlin, memory-leaks, callback, android-viewpager2

So my problem is that I created a OnPageChangeCallback (successfully) BUT i am not sure how to unregister it to avoid memory leak...

this is my mainActivity file everything is working properly otherwise :

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    lateinit var viewPager: ViewPager2

    lateinit var navigationView: BottomNavigationView

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        val view = binding.root
        setContentView(view)

        viewPager = binding.viewPager
        val adapter = ViewPagerAdapter(supportFragmentManager, lifecycle)
        viewPager.adapter = adapter

        navigationView = binding.bottomNavigation

        navigationView.setOnItemSelectedListener { item ->
            when(item.itemId){
                R.id.nav_home -> viewPager.currentItem = 0
                R.id.nav_info -> viewPager.currentItem = 1
            }
            true
        }

        viewPager.registerOnPageChangeCallback(object : ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback(){
            override fun onPageSelected(position: Int) {
                super.onPageSelected(position)
                when(position){
                    0 -> navigationView.menu.findItem(R.id.nav_home).isChecked = true
                    1 -> navigationView.menu.findItem(R.id.nav_info).isChecked = true
                }
            }
        })
    }
    
    // I am not sure I should do it this way 
    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        // I don't know how to put the callback in parameter (the ?? marks)
        viewPager.unregisterOnPageChangeCallback(??)
    }
}
```

If anyone can help me I want to learn how to do things properly I went to the android documentation but I didn't understand how to do it :/

Answer (score 1):

As for Pager documentation

> Remove a callback that was previously added via registerOnPageChangeCallback(ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback).
> Params:
> callback – callback to remove

So to remove callback you'll need to save your ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback() in a variable and then pass it to unregisterOnPageChangeCallback in OnDestroy lifecycle method.

Answer (score 1):

Sharing the Java code to register and unregister the callback.

in the onResume() method add this function.
binding.viewPager2.registerOnPageChangeCallback(viewPagerCallback);

```
ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback viewPagerCallback = new ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
            super.onPageScrolled(position, positionOffset, positionOffsetPixels);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            super.onPageSelected(position);
            Log.i(TAG, "position ->   " + position);
            currentPagePosition = position;

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
            super.onPageScrollStateChanged(state);
        }
    };
```

and in onPause() add this function.
binding.viewPager2.unregisterOnPageChangeCallback(viewPagerCallback);

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Pressing the Back button was causing my ViewPager2 to fire one of these events and it was breaking my app. I have this final project due in 7 hours, so thank you very much!